# Mapping the domain name in GCP app engine with the older version of the application

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform

I have a Flask application running already in GCP App Engine. But after adding a new feature, I encountered an error. I tried solving it, but it is taking time, so my plan is if it is doable, to map the older version of the application url, with the existing domain name. Is it possible, and how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need for this. I was having real trouble figuring this out, then later I found that, we can easily switch between different versions of our application in App Engine by going to App Engine -> Versions -> Select any older version you want -> Migrate traffic (present at the top). It will do your job. There is no need of mapping url of the older version with the domain name.